# How to apply If Then to a range of cells using VBA

Tags: vba, conditional-statements

I'm new to VBA and one of the examples I'm working through (below), is using an If function; in this case, depending on what the 'score' is in A1, some text will be displayed in B1.

I understand that alright, but I was wondering how you would apply that to a range of cells. Say from A1 to A10, depending on the score, text is displayed in B1 to B10.

I've tried searching and I've tried using FOR loops but it displays only the text for the last entry in column A.

Can anyone please help explain the 'standard' way of applying that type of thing to a range of cells?

Thanks

```
Dim note As Integer, score_comment As String
note = Range("A1")

'Comments based on the score
If note = 6 Then
    score_comment = "Excellent score !"
ElseIf note = 5 Then
    score_comment = "Good score"
ElseIf note = 4 Then
    score_comment = "Satisfactory score"
ElseIf note = 3 Then
    score_comment = "Unsatisfactory score"
ElseIf note = 2 Then
    score_comment = "Bad score"
ElseIf note = 1 Then
    score_comment = "Terrible score"
Else
    score_comment = "Zero score"
End If

'Comments in B1
Range("B1") = score_comment
```

Comment: One way would be to `loop` over the range `A1:A10` and apply the condition to each range

Comment: Thanks @AlexP How would I do that exactly? My problem is inside the For loop, I'm not sure what to define 'note' as.  I was thinking of doing;  'For Each cell in rng' where rng is set as the range A1:A10, but then I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

'lastRow is the amount of rows in columns 1 (dynamic)
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = 1 Then
        Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Comment ONE"
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1).Value = 2 Then
        Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Comment TWO"
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1).Value = 3 Then
        Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Comment THREE"
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1).Value = 4 Then
        Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Comment FOUR"
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1).Value = 5 Then
        Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Comment FIVE"
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1).Value = 6 Then
        Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Comment SIX"
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
Sub LoopExample()
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range, note as integer
    Set rng = Range("A1:A10")

    For Each cl In rng
        note = cl.value

        If note = 6 Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1) = "Excellent score !"
        ElseIf note = 5 Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1) = "Good score"
        ElseIf note = 4 Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1) = "Satisfactory score"
        ElseIf note = 3 Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1) = "Unsatisfactory score"
        ElseIf note = 2 Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1) = "Bad score"
        ElseIf note = 1 Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1) = "Terrible score"
        Else
            cl.Offset(0, 1) = "Zero score"
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Notes:

1. `note` is defined in the loop
2. `offset(0,1)` gets the adjancent cell in column B. No need for `score_comment` now

Comment: Thanks @Alex P,  it's given me a lot to work with and learn from, thanks for the help! Appreciate it

Comment: No problem. If the answer works for you then please accept as correct so that it can be marked as 'answered'. Thanks